# ProgressDialog with custom image

Tags: android

I am using the default progress Dialog of Android (indeterminate)

```
ProgressDialog diag = new ProgressDialog(this);
diag.setIndeterminate();
diag.show();
```

However my client didn't like the image so he provided me with one PNG that has picture (which supposed to rotate/spins ).

Is there a way I can replace it in the ProgressDIalog so it spins my image instead? Or how can I achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a drawable with animation (e.g. ./res/drawable/anim1.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

Then add it as an indeterminate drawable:

```
    ProgressDialog diag = new ProgressDialog(this);
    diag.setIndeterminate(true);
    //here is the trick:
    diag.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anim1, null));     
    diag.show();
```

However, this may not work smoothly on older versions of Android.

P.S. you can make animation faster by increasing degree (from 360 to 360n, where n >= 1. If the image is top-bottom symmetrical, you can use 180) as it seems that this kind of animation does not support `android:frameDuration` or `android:frameCount` if set like this.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try, but why are you saying it does not work on previous versions

Comment: @Snake, it *may* not work smoothly on older versions (pre-Lolipop). I did not test it on Kitkat or earlier so I cannot state that it'll work seamlessly there.

Comment: Ohhh I see. You are saying it may not work on older versions because you didn't test it there, not because you think there is a problem or heard of a problem?

Comment: Yes. If I were you, I'd test on the devices with your minSdk just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ?

diag.setIcon(R.drawable.customImg);

Answer (score 0):

You can use setContentView(view) on the progressDialog
like 
`diag.setContentView(R.id.layout_with_image)`

or create the ImageView and set it as Content view

`ImageView iv=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
iv.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.your_image);
diag.setContentView(iv);`

Comment: You can add rotate animation to it,just like other views